# Download Varbinary files in C# using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, invalidoperationexception, varbinary

I am currently trying to download a total of 30.000 varbinary files from SQL Server to my local drive. I am using Entity Framework to make a connection to download these files in a .NET console application. Which looks like the following.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext())
    {
        var files = from t in db.StandardExpenceFiles
                    select t;

        foreach (StandardExpenceFiles t in files)
        {
            if (t.MimeType != null && t.FileName != null && t.FileContent != null)
            {
                if (t.StandardExpenseShortDescription.Contains("/ "))
                {
                    t.StandardExpenseShortDescription = t.StandardExpenseShortDescription.Replace("/ ", string.Empty);
                }

                string ext = t.MimeType.Substring(t.MimeType.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);

                try
                {
                    if (!File.Exists("path"))
                    {
                        using (FileStream fs = File.Create("path"))
                        {
                            fs.Write(t.FileContent, 0, t.FileContent.Length);
                            fs.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works but after a while it crashes because the memory isn't getting disposed the right way. as you can see in the screenshot. It causes lag which results in a sqlclient timeout.

[image]

I am new to Entity Framework and I don't know how to use it in a clean way. I am looking for a way to fix this or another way to download my files using Entity Framework.

Comment: I removed the sql server tag as this has nothing to do with sql server.

Comment: That *kind of* looks like an exception the framework might produce, except not really. Is that the *exact* text or are you paraphrasing? Please copy the exact text, and an indication of what line it happens on if available.

Comment: The foreach loop is the line that throws the exception

Comment: why do you dispose the filestream explicitly before exiting the foreach? Also, why is there an empty finally block? Also, the catch with just a WriteLine swallows all errors if you do not keep track of the output window, you should certainly rethrow exceptions or handle them otherwise.

Comment: I changed The question to make to problem more clear

Comment: All files get attached to the context. Try `db.StandardExpenceFiles.AsNoTracking()`.

Comment: Still the same result @GertArnold

Comment: OK... I don't understand, because the memory is eaten by piles of byte arrays, that is, all these `FileContent`s. You do dispose the `FileStream`, so there doesn't seem anything left to escape garbage disposal. What if you try `File.WriteAllBytes` instead of creating and disposing a `FileStream`? (Which is easier anyway).